# Función lambda se ejecuta 2 veces con un solo evento recibido

Tags: javascript, nodejs, aws, lambda

Actualmente tengo un lambda que escribe en la base de datos *mysql* y es disparada por un *eventbrigde* que recibe unos registros, ese evento que recibo es el que escribo en la DB. Me he percatado que en los registros de *cloudwatch* la función lambda se ejecuta 2 veces y escribe 2 veces en la DB, en el log de *cloudwatch* salen 2 ID diferentes pero el mismo event.

Realmente no se que puede estar pasando, en *eventbridge*, observo que el evento lo recibo 1 vez.

```js
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  let mysql = require("mysql2/promise");
  const { nombreApi, estado, latencia, fechaTransaccion, region, canal, plan } =
    event.detail;
   
  let connection =await mysql.createConnection({...dbData});

  const [rows] = await connection.query(selectSubsId, [
    canal,
    nombreApi,
  ]);

  const id = rows[0].subscriptionID;

  if (id) {
    const [rows] = await connection.query(insert, [
      fechaTransaccion,
      Number(latencia),
      estado,
      id,
      region,
      plan,
      nombreApi,
      canal,
    ]);
    
    if (rows.affectedRows){ 
      connection.end();
      context.succeed('exitoso');
      return {
        status: "exitoso",
        event: event
      };
      
    }else {
      connection.end();
      context.fail('Fallido');
      return "No se ha podido insertar en la DB";
    }    
  }else {
      context.fail('No existe SubscriptionID');
    return "No existe SubscriptionID";
  }

};
```

Alguna idea de que podría estar sucediendo?

Comment: ya te aseguraste que solamente estes llamando una ves tu lambda, desde donde la consumes?

Comment: Has revisa la duracion de la ejecucion de tu función lambda y el numero máximo de intentos en caso de falla  que tiene definidos?

Comment: Si, solo se llama 1 vez, desde eventbridge solo se llama 1 vez, y se consume desde eventbridge

Comment: Asi es, puse el nro de intento a 0, y ademas la duracion del lambda tiene 1 min y nunca da timeout, siempre termina su ejecucion correctamente sin importar si incremento o decremento la duracion